# How to populate a dictionary of dictionaries from data in a csv file

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have some data regarding class, student id and student name in a csv file, like the following:

4, 3, John (class, sstudent id, student name)

3, 3, Jane

4, 4, Harry

2, 3, Harry

3, 5, Jenny

2, 1, Joe

I need to read the above data into a SortedDictionary> structure, where the outer dictionary stores the class as key, and the inner dictionary stores student id and student name.

My code is a bit like as folllows:

```
string line = string.Empty;
string[] data = null;

SortedDictionary<int, string> studentDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>();
SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<int, string>> classDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<int, string>>();

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(schoolCSV))
{
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        line = sr.ReadLine();
        data = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        studentDictionary.Add(Convert.ToInt32(data[1].Trim()), data[2]);
        // I get error in the above line, when it parses the second row
    }
}
```

I am unable to retrieve it correctly into the sorted dictionary of sorted dictionaries. Could someone please show me the right way?

Comment: Please specify the language you are using and set appropriate tags.

Comment: Right now, your code only has one `studentDictionary`.  You need to create a `studentDictionary` for each class.

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of LINQ might help.

First, you'll need an extension method to convert an `IEnumerable<T>` to a `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace YourNamespace
{
   public static class SortedDictionaryExtensions
   {
      public static SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue> ToSortedDictionary<TSource, TKey, TValue>(
         this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
         Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
         Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector)
      {
         var result = new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>();

         foreach (TSource item in source)
         {
            TKey key = keySelector(item);
            TValue value = valueSelector(item);
            result.Add(key, value);
         }

         return result;
      }
   }
}
```

Then you can combine `GroupBy` with your new extension method to generate the results:

```
SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<int, string>> classDictionary;

classDictionary = File.ReadLines(schoolCSV)
   .Select(line => line.Split(','))
   .Select(data => new 
   { 
      ClassId = int.Parse(data[0]),
      StudentId = int.Parse(data[1]),
      StudentName = data[2]
   })
   .GroupBy(item => item.ClassId, (key, items) => new
   {
      ClassId = key,
      Students = items.ToSortedDictionary(i => i.StudentId, i => i.StudentName)
   })
   .ToSortedDictionary(item => item.ClassId, item => item.Students);
```